# Best Book on Feynman or Leibnitz's differentiation under Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, gaussian-integral

What  the best book to learn about the Feynman technique or Leibnitz's rule about differentiation under Integral sign.

Sometimes you have to pre-decide whether you can solve for the C that comes with Indefinite Integral

Comment: Any real analysis textbook covers that. As for "best", I have no idea what it means..

Comment: Do you want a book with lots of examples or a book that gives rigorous proofs of various versions of the technique? Off-hand, the best reference I know is *Article 118: Integrals containing a parameter* (pp. 281-288) in [**Advanced Calculus**](https://archive.org/details/advancedcalculu00wilsgoog/page/n294/mode/2up) by Edwin Bidwell Wilson (1912). I first discovered this method in Wilson's book in 1997, while looking for interesting supplementary ideas for a strong high school honors calculus class I was teaching, and I immediately recognized that this must be what Feynman **(continued)**

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro yes kind of like that. Thank you so much ^_^

Comment: was talking about in his book. I'd gotten a copy of Feynman's book in 1985 when it first appeared, and had read it several times by then. I posted a detailed example of this method [in sci.math on 8 April 2000](https://web.archive.org/web/20021115005035/http://mathforum.org/discuss/sci.math/m/264661/264663), which is probably one of the first times this was explicitly explained on the internet (the only earlier explanation I know are [these 1990 posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sci.math/Feynman$20integration$20surely$20joking%7Csort:date/sci.math/-4SfUF9Owks/XLLsE7bXZf8J)).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro hopefully I'll go through all of them ^_^

Comment: If I get a chance sometime (don't have time now; in fact, leaving home to go somewhere right now), I'll see if I can dig up some more references (for an actual answer), although probably just googling things like "under the integral" and "parameter" with "integration" in google-books or archive.org will give lots of books having sections devoted to this topic. FYI, I have a .pdf scan of a 46 page 1927 MS thesis by Herman Edwin Ellingson, **Integrals Containing a Parameter** (University of Iowa, under Edward Wilson Chittenden) that contains a lot of examples. See my profile for my email.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro this is beyond my expectation, have seen tons of people online, nobody was as helpful as you are, truly grateful