# Elementary question on integration of a fraction with square root

Tags: integration

During the process of solving a differential equation which appears in the calculations of a particle physics problem, I encounter the following integral:
$$\int\dfrac{d\phi}{\sqrt{a\phi^4+b\phi^2+c}}$$
where $c$ is a constant from a previous integration and $a,b$ are some physical constants.

Is it possible to integrate this analytically? My knowledge on this is quite a bit rusty. Any hints on how to tackle the calculation?

Comment: The form will likely depend on whether $b^2 - 4ac$ is negative, zero, or positive. Did you check some standard integral tables, such as [**CRC Standard Mathematical Tables and Formulae**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1439835489) or [**Schaum's Outline of Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1260010538) or Abramowitz/Stegun's [**Handbook of Mathematical Functions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486612724)? When I was in college pretty much every physics and engineering (electrical, mechanical) major had at least one of these (and/or a similar such handbook).

Comment: Perhaps something in [the references listed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4418786/13130) will help, especially the freely available/viewable books by Bromwich, Edwards, Hardy, MacNeish.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral